# (Weird) Matrix notation with a colon?

Tags: matrices, notation

In my textbook (for digital circuits), there is the next notation for a matrix:

> A matrix with n rows and m columns can be written as $A^{1:n}_{1:m}$

Since I'm new to matrices altogether, I'm struggling to understand what the "$1:$" is supposed to represent.

I tried to google it, but I don't even know what this notation is called - I cannot even find a notation without the number one with a colon, or any other number in the place of 1.

Comment: Most likely $\ell \,:\, m$ means "$\ell$ to $m$", i.e. $[\ell,\ell+1,\ell+2,\cdots,m-1,m]$. It's a notation I'm seeing in the linear algebra textbook I'm studying right now, and presumably has origins in MATLAB. An equivalent notation may be

$$A = (a_{i,j})_{1 \le i \le n , 1 \le j \le m}$$

or $A \in \mathbb{F}^{n \times m}$.

Comment: Could you include the title and author of the textbook? Perhaps someone who has also read that book will know.

Comment: @moofasa perhaps i should've been more specific - it's not really a textbook, it's a PowerPoint presentation not written in English and (probably) only meant for students of this one profesor. It is a bit weird we don't have other sources, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

As the comments suggested - yes, notation $l:m$ means "from $l$ to $m$", therefore, $A^{1:n}_{1:m}$ means "*matrix $A$ with rows from $1$ to $n$ and columns from $1$ to $m$.*"

**Potentially wrong further explanation:**

This makes sense when performing operations on matrices:

$C^{1:n}_{1:m} = A^{1:n}_{1:t} * B^{1:t}_{1:m}$, where $*$ is some operator. Then one element of the matrix is calculated as such:

$c^{i}_{j} = /(a^{i}_{1:t} * b^{1:t}_{j})$

This means the operation for one element $c$ is calculated by performing a row reduction on $a$ elements (in the $i$-th column) and a column reduction on the  $b$ elements (in the $j$-th row).